# Doit-on traduire les prénoms ?

Tags: traduction, prénoms

Je suis en train de traduire une histoire d'anglais en français et je me demande s'il est préférable de traduire les prénoms utilisés ?

Par exemple, *"Kyle"*, *"Kimber"*, etc.

Ces prénoms sont typiquement anglophones et donc détonnent légèrement en français.

Dois-je utiliser des noms francophones équivalents, tels que: *"Kevin"*, *"Karine"*, etc. ou garder les originaux ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ça a été la mode très longtemps, en France, de traduire tous les noms. Je pense à Frodon Sacquet (dont le nom reprend l'idée de sac de Frodo Baggins) ou de Pierre Parker (parce que Spider Man ne pouvait s'appeler que Pierre… pour une raison…), allant jusqu'à franciser les lieux : les séries et dessins-animés des années 80 se passaient souvent en France alors qu'elles étaient écrites pour les États-Unis ou le Japon.

La question qu'il faut se poser avant de prendre cette décision est : **est-ce que le nom a une importance dans l'histoire ?**

Le nom peut avoir une importance tel quel. Il ne faut donc pas le traduire.

Exemple :

> Kyle adorait son prénom, particulièrement le Y, car il symbolisait pour lui le choix entre deux routes, entre deux avenirs, ce choix qu'il avait dû faire tellement de fois durant sa vie.

Le nom peut avoir une importance à cause d'un jeu de mot possible à traduire. Dans ce cas, il faut le traduire.

Exemple (spoiler de Harry Potter) :

> *Tom Elvis Jedusor*, l'anagramme de *Je suis Voldemort*. Traduction de *Tom Marvolo Riddle*, l'anagramme de *I am Lord Voldemort*.

Si aucun de ces deux cas ne se présente, ni ne se présentera dans la suite de l'histoire (qui n'est peut-être pas encore écrite), alors c'est juste une question de choix personnel du traducteur. À mon avis (mais ça reste mon avis), l'auteur avait une raison de choisir ces noms pour ses personnages. Les modifier dénature un peu l'histoire. Dans le doute, pourquoi ne pas demander à l'auteur lui-même ?

Comment: Pierre et Peter sont souvent donnés comme équivalents (Saint Pierre dans la Bible est Saint Peter en anglais). Kyle n'a pas un tel équivalent à ma connaissance. Sacquet permettait de rendre Baggins accessible au lectorat français, mais je n'ai jamais compris la nasalisation du prénom. Quant à l'exemple en spoiler, la raison première de sa traduction est le jeu de mot sur le patronyme, que le personnage déteste et qu'il fallait rendre accessible à un public français (assez peu de personnages ont vu leur nom traduit dans ce livre ; je ne pense qu'à Neuville et Tom).

Comment: @Chop: Je suppose que la nasalisation est à l'image des dieux grecs, par exemple Apollon / Apollo.

Comment: @mouviciel Comparaison intéressante. D'après [le Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Apollon), Apollo est la version latine et descend de la racine grecque Apollon. J'aurais pensé que pour le français, on avait pu prendre directement la racine grecque.

Answer (score 5):

Dans le passé, on ne traduisait pas les nom propres. 
À ce titre, [George Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Moore_%28novelist%29) écrivait:

> Tous les noms propres […] doivent être rigoureusement respectés

Toutefois, rien n'est vraiment tranché à ce sujet. Ainsi, [Ballard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._G._Ballard)  et [Grass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%BCnter_Grass), notamment, ont proposé d’étudier la traduction des noms propres, le premier en anglais, le second en allemand.

Documentation intéressante à lire :

**[La traduction des noms propres: une étude en corpus](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.1605.pdf)**

Answer (score 4):

En néerlandais, autre langue du pays d'Hergé, Tintin se nomme Kuifje. Wikipédia montre que [les noms des personnages des aventures de Tintin s'adaptent à chaque pays](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_noms_des_personnages_de_Tintin_en_langues_%C3%A9trang%C3%A8res). Une hypothèse: Tintin, ainsi que «Le tour du monde en 80 jours» cité dans la réponse de Begueradj s'adressent entre autres à un jeune public qui connaît moins les us et habitudes des autres pays. Est-ce que ce serait une raison suffisante pour traduire les noms propres?

Je ne crois pas que dans les «grands» romans on traduise les noms propres. Un cas intéressant, est-ce que George devient Georges lorsqu'un roman est traduit de l'anglais au français?

Answer (score 4):

Il est important de prendre en considération le contexte (lieu géographique), si il est prépondérant dans l'histoire ou non.

Par exemple, si il s'agit d'une histoire pour enfant sans lieu, ceci ne pose pas de problème.

Si l'histoire se passe dans un quartier de Londres, on s'attendra à lire "William" pour une famille anglaise plutôt que son équivalent français "Guillaume".

Answer (score 0):

Normalement, en traduction littéraire, on ne traduit pas les prénoms. Après, la question peut être posée dans certains contextes. Vous trouverez plus d'informations à ce sujet dans cet article : https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/traduire-les-pr%C3%A9noms-pierre-jeanson

Comment: Bonjour ! Quels sont ces contextes ? L'un deux correspond-il à celui de la question ? Donc que dis l'article au sujet de cette situation ? Ce que l'auteur de la question dit cadre-t-il avec la raison sociolinguistique ou phonétique évoquée dans l'article ?